# Does covariance of $X$ and $X^2$ depend on the range of $X$?

Tags: random-variable, expected-value, covariance

Consider the random variables $X$. First suppose that $X\sim U(0, 1)$ (i.e. it has uniform distribution over $[0, 1]$). By simple transformation, I found that the density for $Y = X^2$ is: $p_Y(y) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$, and the density of $Z = X^3$ is $p_Z(z) = \frac{1}{3y^{2/3}}$. From these, I got the expectation values of $Y$ and $Z$ to be $\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{1}{4}$ respectively. Now consider the covariance of $X$ and $Y=X^2$.
$$\text{cov}(X, X^2) = \mathbb{E}(X^3)-\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(X^2) = \frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{12}$$

However, now if I change the range of $X$ so that $X\sim U(-1, 1)$, I get,
$$\text{cov}(X, X^2) = \mathbb{E}(X^3)-\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(X^2) = 0-0\times \mathbb{E}(X^2) = 0$$

My first question is, how is it possible that the covariance changes if we change the range of random variables (what is the intuitive reason)? Or am I making some mistake in the calculation? Second, since $X$ and $Y$, though are dependent, are not linearly dependent. Then shouldn't we get $\text{cov}(X, X^2) = 0$ even in the first case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are asking two questions.

a) Why does covariance change if I look at different ranges (keeping min, max difference the same)?  I think that's easier to draw. e.g. what is the covariance/correlation  of $X$ and $|X|$?

Between (-1,1) correlation is zero, between (0, 2) it is 1 and between (-2,0) it is -1.

b) If the max, min difference increases (for your uniform case), then your standard deviation increases.  So it is  useful to think of covariance as correlation($X,Y$) * sd($X$) * sd($Y$).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @seanv507's point (that the range directly affects the covariance amplitude), the covariance and the *correlation* between $X$ and $X^2$ depends on both range and position. For example, if $X$ is distributed in a small range around $1$, $X$ will be close to $X^2$, i.e. $X^2\approx X$, the correlation becomes close to $1$.

Comment: I think, additionally, when the range becomes $[-1, 1]$, the best fit to the data is a horizontal line whereas when the range is $[0, 1]$, a tilted line with positive slope. Is this right?

Comment: If you're talking about the best fit to the data *generated* by both distributions, they both will be horizontal lines. Here, the key comparison is between expectations.

Comment: I am talking about the best fit for a scatterplot of $X$ and $X^2$

Comment: ok, that's right.